# c++ get camera position in world coordinates (opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv, extrinsic-parameters, pose-estimation

**Ok solved it.
first I gonna use a Matlab tool and the chessboardthingie to get the intrinsic parameters.
And the i ll use cv::solvePnP()**

Yeah I used the search but unforunately it didnt help me alot.

As the title says I have to find the camera-coordinates in real world.
But I am also facing some problems concerning opencv commands.
Till now I know some points in the image and the corresponding World coordinates.
(worst case 6 points are known)

To get the camera-cooridnates I thought of using the formula:

transp(x,y,z)= - transp(R)*t , where R and t are the extrinsic parameters

so now my proble is: how to calculate R and t ?
I mean does an opencv function exist that solves this problem?
Cause actually there are a lot camer calibrate functions.
Or do I have to first calculate the intrinsic parameters ?

edit: here is the function i meant: 
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/calib3d_camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera2

but i dont know how the parameters should look like.
How can I initialize manually a for example 3x6 Matrix
like cv::Mat ([[x1] [y1] [z1]] .... [[x6] [y6] [z6]])

Answer (score 0):

The R and T matrices are the Rotation and Translations between the two camera views in a stereo system

Presumably you could find the position of the camera relative to a single target - once you have a calibrated camera and a known target - but the description of the software is aimed at a stereo pair.

Chapter 11 and 12 of the [openCV book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516130.do) give good descriptions